# Show counter text, every four beats

Tags: javascript, html

I have a counter and every four steps plays a sound. Every four steps is a meter.
What I want is,  every 4 steps of 32, to write on the screen 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

For example:
[image]

What I have made works 100%, but is there a better way to do that and to save space? Thanks!

if(Step == 0) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "1";

if(Step == 4) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "2";

if(Step == 8) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "3";

if(Step == 12) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "4";

if(Step == 16) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "5";

if(Step == 20) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "6";

if(Step == 24) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "7";

if(Step == 28) document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "8";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
if(Step%4 == 0){
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Step/4 + 1;
}
```